# Is $n=8{,}574{,}796{,}230$ the smallest squarefree number $n$ with $gnu(n)>10^6$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, gap, groups-enumeration

The number of groups of order $n$ (gnu(n)) can be calculated by a closed formula, if $n$ is squarefree. I could calculate the values with GAP, additionally, I programmed a version in PARI/GP, working fine. I found

$$gnu(8{,}574{,}796{,}230)=1{,}243{,}776$$

and I wonder, whether this is the smallest example $n$ with $gnu(n)>10^6$.

I am looking for a faster way because it takes long (also with GAP) to simply apply brute-force.

It is clear that two prime factors are not enough because $gnu(n)$ is at most $2$ in this case.

If $n$ has $3$ prime factors, of which the smallest is $p$, then $gnu(n)$ is at most $p+4$.

I worked out an upper bound for $4$ prime factors, which I cannot remember, but I am pretty sure, that $4$ factors is not enough either.

> Is there an efficient way to calculate the smallest example ?

Comment: Just to reiterate my warning (see README.txt in your new mini GAP installation) - it has limited functionality because in particular it has only 4 packages. For example, FactInt speeds up integer factorisation, and it's missing. You may add packages one after another downloading  individual archives from their overview pages listed at http://www.gap-system.org/Packages/packages.html

Comment: But yes, even with a full GAP installation a sequential computation will take a while. Nothing with $gnu(n) > 10^6$ found overnight for $n \le 246464745$.

Comment: I have checked that the smallest solution must have at least $5$ prime factors. Maybe, this speeds up the search :)

Comment: Thanks, I think so - now at 365295805. Still a long way to go.

Comment: For numbers with more than $5$ prime factors, I checked that the smallest example must be greater than $1.7\times 10^9$. Probably the smallest example must have more than $5$ prime factors, but I did not prove that yet.

Comment: That check is still running - now at 3228181082.

Comment: I left it running for a while, and today it is at 6519456618. Hope to give an answer soon. BTW, could you please add a reference to the formula to the question?

Comment: @Alexander Konovalov Did you omit the numbers with less than $5$ prime factors or not ? You can find the formula at mathworld and I found a paper dealing with gnu(n) for squarefree n. Just use the keywords squarefree number group order and click on the first hit. The formula is not easy, but it is not too difficult to program it. If you have PARI/GP, I can display the program I used.

Comment: Yes, after you said that you "have checked that the smallest solution must have at least 5 prime factors", I've started to omit those with less than 5. Please copy and paste a link to mathworld - the search ordering seems to differ from yours, I can't see it. And I have PARI/GP, so interested to look at your code, too, thanks.

Comment: PARI-code : groupnumber(n)={su=0;fordiv(n,m,w1=factor(m);w2=factor(n/m);w1=component(w1,1);w2=component(w2,1);p=1;for(j=1,length(w2),nu=0;for(k=1,length(w1),if(Mod(w1[k],w2[j])==1,nu=nu+1));p=p*(w2[j]^nu-1)/(w2[j]-1));su=su+p);su}

Comment: mathworld-link : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FiniteGroup.html (See formula $6$)

Comment: Do you know how reliable the NrSmallGroups-command and the NumberCFGroup-command for cubefree orders are ? Unfortunately, the ConstructAllGroups-command may fail to give the correct value of $gnu(n)$. Someone should check for which values $n$ this is the case.

Comment: I do not agree with the wording "ConstructAllGroups-command may fail to give the correct value of gnu(n)" - it does what is documented. For cubefree groups, NrSmallGroups will look at Small Groups Library without using NumberCFGroup, if that's what you mean by "how reliable".

Comment: See also on accuracy checks for the CubreFree package: http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/pkg/cubefree/htm/CHAP002.htm#SECT005

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, $n=8574796230$ is the smallest square-free number $n$ such that the number of groups of order $n$ is greater than $10^6$.

The number of groups of this order can be calculated in GAP as follows:

```
gap> NrSmallGroups(8574796230);
1243776
```

I did not have a chance to try anything better than a brute force approach, or even parallelising the check, so I was patient enough to run the following script to check that there are no smaller numbers with this property:

```
IsWorthTrying:=function(n) 
local d,x; 
d :=Factors(n); 
if Length(d)>4 and ForAll(Collected(d),x -> x[2]=1) then 
  return true; 
else 
  return false; 
fi;
end;

k:=1;
repeat 
  k:=k+1; 
  if IsWorthTrying(k) then 
    nr:=NrSmallGroups(k); 
    Print(k, " : ", nr, "                 \r");  
  else 
    nr:=0; 
  fi; 
until nr > 10^6; 
Print("\n\n");
```

As @Peter said, "the smallest solution must have at least $5$ prime factors", so it was checking only those with 5 or more prime factors. It was running from December 16th till February 6th, except maybe several days when it was stopped and then restarted from the point where it was at the time of the shutdown.